# Defining a massive but known function in z3

Tags: math, z3, z3py

I want to use z3 to solve a satisfiability problem in pure mathematics. The solver would have to reason about a function of sort `Function('mult', BitVecSort(8), BitVecSort(8), BitVecSort(8), BitVecSort(8), BitVecSort(8), BitVecSort(8), BitVecSort(8))`. This function is already completely known a priori, so in theory we could define it by inputting all constraints of the form

```
mult(0, 26, 1, 0, 78, 1) == 1,
mult(11, 5, 1, 149, 9, 2) == 4,
mult(23, 8, 1, 116, 11, 1) == 10, ...
```

but this is unfeasible due to the massive number of constraints needed.

However, there are only 125,501 output values that are very hard to compute, and every other value is easy to compute once those are known. I can input all 125,501 constraints in z3 and the solver builds a model in a couple minutes (I used `Tactic('bv').solver()`).

There are some general statements that hold for `mult`, like
`ForAll([s1,s2,f1,f2,v1,v2], mult(s1,f1,v1,s2,f2,v2) == mult(s2,f2,v2,s1,f1,v1))`,
but already adding this constraint takes an unreasonably long time to check (it's been running for more than 24h now).

Is there an easier way I could import my function in z3? Is it simply too large for z3 to reason about it efficiently?

Comment: If the function is known, the best way would be to simply implement it in z3py, instead of giving it case-by-case like that. Massive or not, it would be best to just write the function as is if you really want to reason about it.

Comment: What do you mean by implementing it in z3py? It's already a python function, but it takes roughly 300 lines to define, and even then it relies on an external file that took months to generate. If I could somehow use the z3py API to register the function directly that would solve all my problems, but I have found no way of doing that so far.

Comment: You cannot use z3 to take in an arbitrary Python function. Instead, you'll have to rewrite it as a z3py function. That is, you actually use the z3's API to code the same. This doesn't mean it's trivial to do so, but it's the only way that I know how. (Other than enumerating all the cases as you mentioned, which is prohibitively expensive.)

Comment: Well defining this function from scratch took some specialized code and several months of supercomputer time, so writing it in z3py is not feasible. But the real meat of the function is only 125,501 input values which z3 seems to handle quite well. I was just wondering if z3 can recover the whole function from those values in a reasonable time, since even just adding that `ForAll` constraint has made the checking take more than a day already.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely z3 will recover the remaining values from your 125K of inputs. You'll most likely have to write quantified assertions to determine the rest, and SMT solvers don't do well in the presence of quantifiers. (Just the sheer size of the problem will probably send the e-matching algorithm spinning.) SMT solvers shine at quantifier-free subsets of first-order logics; such as bit-vectors, booleans, arithmetic, reals, etc.

Comment: I agree, the only way to go about this is to translate the entire function into either the SMT2 format or into Z3 API calls. This is likely not nearly as complicated as it might sound. Since it's already over bit-vectors all the basic operations just get a different (SMT2) name and loops can be unrolled as they are likely bounded to a small number of iterations anyways. Don't assume that Z3 will magically infer any part of the function that you don't specify - it won't, or it will at least take huge amounts of time to do so.